# Delete image and thumbnail created by MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage

Tags: android

I realize

[MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage (ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.graphics.Bitmap,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

will create 2 files (image and thumbnail)

How can I delete both created images?

Answer (score 1):

use this command using the id of the images you wish to delete:

```
mediaStoreIds.add(mediaStoreId);
context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(mediaStoreIds.get(id))});
```

and the following to delete the thumbnails:

```
mediaStoreIds.add(mediaStoreId);
context.getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(mediaStoreIds.get(id))});
```